# image is not loading from mysql which is stored as imagepath

Tags: android, mysql, android-bitmap

I want to load text and image (stored as image path) from mysql db to listview. I am able top fetch the text but the image is not loading. Gone through a lot of tutorial and SO questions but not able to resolve it.

I tried with Bitmap like below

```
 Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path of your img1");
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

not working. Tried with File file = ... also but that also not working. Below is the complete code with latest change but that throws an network exception.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final sharedcollect sc;
private final ArrayList<Mdetails> mdetails;

public MovieAdapter(sharedcollect sc, ArrayList<Mdetails> mdetails) {
    this.sc = sc;
    this.mdetails = mdetails;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mdetails.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mdetails.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Mdetails md = mdetails.get(position);
   String moviename = md.moviename;
    String year = md.year;
    String imdbrating = md.irating;
    String rottenrating = md.rating;
    String genere = md.genere;
    String Image = md.Image;
    Bitmap bimage;


    View view= LayoutInflater.from(sc).inflate(R.layout.custlayout,null);
    TextView mname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.moviename);
    TextView myear = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    TextView iname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.irating);
    TextView rname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView gname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.genere);

    bimage = getBitmapFromURL(Image);
    ImageView iview= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

   mname.setText(moviename);
    myear.setText(" "+year);
    iname.setText("  "+irating  );
    rname.setText("  "+rating);
    gname.setText("        " + genere);
    iview.setImageBitmap(bimage);

    return view;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String image) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(image);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
   }
 }
```

What is wrong with this code?

LOGCAT:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.moviefilter.as, PID: 20319
   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
        at com.moviefilter.allmovieratings.MovieAdapter.getBitmapFromURL(MovieAdapter.java:85)
        at com.moviefilter.allmovieratings.MovieAdapter.getView(MovieAdapter.java:66)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: are you just store image path in database???

Comment: Yes, Only image path.

Comment: well the exception is from network so have you check your internet connection..??

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> provided necessary permission and also text is fetching properly.

Comment: post your full logcat!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the internet permission to manifest file. For images I would recommend using the popular [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. You can load the image using a single statement like `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` It handles image loading and caching automatically.

Edit: This exception is caused when you try to do network operation on main thread. You need to use something like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding) for network operations. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288544/5925259) example for loading using AsyncTask. If you want simple solution to this, use the library I mentioned above.

Comment: is it supported from AP 15?

Comment: @user2269164 yes it is.

Comment: @user2269164 I have updated my post for AsyncTask example as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this.It will solve your error

```
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {                                                                       

                            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;                              
                            // create instance of InputStream and pass URL
                            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imagelink).openStream();
                            // decode stream and initialize bitmap
                            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                            in.close();

                        }


                        //Your code goes here
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: @user2269164 you have to use that in a thread to avoid exception